# Kotlin cannot access protected abstract method

Tags: kotlin

I have the following classes structure:

```
abstract class Abstr{
    protected abstract fun m()
}

class Child : Abstr(){
    private val subChild: Abstr = Child()

    override fun m() = subChild.m()// Error:(12, 18) Kotlin: Cannot access 'm': it is protected in 'Abstr'
}
```

I got an exception `Kotlin: Cannot access 'm': it is protected in 'Abstr'`

It little bit confusing, because the same structure is legal for java.

According to [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html#classes-and-interfaces)

> - protected — visible inside this class only + visible in subclasses too;

Is it bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is designed behavior

Protected modifier in Kotlin similar to Java, but has additional restrictions.

**Protected in Java**:

- Visible for inheritance
- Visible in package

**Protected in Kotlin**:

- Visible for inheritance

So, according to the code in question we cannot access protected method

```
class Child : Abstr(){
    private val subChild: Abstr = Child()

    override fun m() = subChild.m() //Trying to access not inherited method 
}
```

There is similar restriction in Java, when we trying to access protected member from another package:

```
// FILE: a/SuperClass.java
package a;
public class SuperClass {
    protected void superFunction() {}
}

// FILE: b/ChildClass.java
package b;
public class ChildClass extends SuperClass {
    void testFunction() {
        ((SuperClass) new ChildClass()).superFunction(); // ERROR: superFunction() has protected access in a.SuperClass
    }
}
```

There is answer in issue tracker from Kotlin team:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-21048

Answer (score 4):

The current behavior is by design.

By calling `subChild.m()` you're trying to access an instance of `Abstr` from outside the object, so `protected` access prevents you from doing this.

#### Let me show you a short example to clarify the case

```
    abstract class ParentCl {
        protected var num = 1
        protected open fun m(){
        }
    }
    
    class ChildCl : ParentCl() {
        private val a0 : ParentCl = ChildCl()
        override fun m() {
            super.m() // 1-st case
            num = 2 // 2-nd case            
            a0.m() // 3-rd case
        }
    }
```

1. You're calling the `protected` `ParentCl`'s fun from the child class. It will work fine.
2. You're modifying of `protected` variable from the child class. It will work fine.
3. *You're calling the `protected` fun **outside** the context of the child class. This will not work.*

#### Depends on what was your goal there are two solutions:

1. If you wanted to **call m() from ParentCl** you need to change the visibility from `protected` to `internal` or `public`.
2. If you wanted to **call m() from the child class** you need to declare the variable without the explicit type of its parent: `private val subChild = Child()`.

*Note: in case you will **use m() from other children** of ParentCl you need to enlarge the visibility scope inside child class: `public override fun m() {...}`*

Answer (score 0):

It's possible a bug.

When i added {} everything became ok.

```
abstract class Abstr{
    protected abstract fun m()
}

class Child : Abstr(){
    private val subChild: Abstr = Child()

    override fun m() {
        subChild.m() // Compiles fine
    }
}
```

Create issue on https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/

or write on Slack 
http://slack.kotlinlang.org/

Comment: You've used `subChild: Child = Child()` and this is the reason why "everything became ok" not because of the Kotlin's bug. The original code explicitly defines the type: `subChild: Abstr = Child()`.

Comment: @Val oh, forget to change back, anyway code compiles fine. Thanks for edit.

Comment: @icarumbas your code does not compile. The same error as I got

Answer (score -1):

protected — same as private + visible in subclasses too;

```
abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(getLayoutResId())

} 

   protected open fun getPageTitle() = SpannableString(getString(R.string.app_name))
}
```

In your sub class

```
class EditProfileActivity : BaseActivity() {
    override fun getPageTitle(): SpannableString = SpannableString(getString(R.string.edit_profile))
}
```

See the doc for more details

[visibility-modifiers](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/visibility-modifiers.html)

[Classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html)